# call subclass methods by superclass reference

Tags: java

I have code like this:

```
String stringRef = new String("Java");                    // (1)

System.out.println("(2): " + stringRef.getClass());       // (2)
System.out.println("(3): " + stringRef.length());         // (3)

Object objRef = stringRef;                                // (4)

// System.out.println("(5): " + objRef.length());            // (5) Not OK.
System.out.println("(6): " + objRef.equals("Java"));
```

Why can I not call `length()` in line (5); and for which class will `equals()` be called in line (6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do that, as subclass's methods are not in your super class. In this case, though String is a subclass of Object as length() is not declared in java.lang.Object class its no possible to call length on its instance.

equals() method however is overriden in string class, thus Strings's equals() will be invoked

Comment: I know that.But why..because by Object objRef = stringRef; we are assigning the stringreference to objReference.. means now objRef point to the same as stringRef.

Comment: but during compile time its the object reference that matters. equals() however is overriden in your subclass String, thus due to runtime polymorphism String's equals() is invoked at runtime

Answer (score 1):

`equals` is declared on `Object` so you can call it; `length` isn't. The compiler will not try to determine what exactly object type is referred to by `objRef`; it works only with the knowledge that it is an Object.

The Java compiler statically resolves the signature of the method to call, based on the static type of the expression to the left of the dot operator. The concept of polymorphism and dynamic dispatch applies only to the resolution of which overriding method to call.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler, `objRef` is an instance of `Object`, which does not have any method named `length()`. On the other hand, `equals()` is a method coming from `Object`, and inherited in `String`, that's why the program behaves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The length() method is unique to Strings.  By assigning that to an Object, Java no longer knows that it is a String.

The old clichè: All circles are shapes, not all shapes are circles.

If you do the following it will work:

```
System.out.println("(5): " + ((String)objRef).length());
```

Here you typecast to a String first, and then you call length().

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `Type` reference, you can ONLY call methods or access fields that are public and visible to `Type`, i.e `Type`'s own methods or public ones of `Type`s superclasses.

In this case Object defines the methods `equals` and many others, and thus you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

It is the type of reference not the actual object, that defines what all methods that can be accessed.So you cant access subclass methods using a super class refernece, eventhough your superclass reference is holding a subclass object.

Comment: But it is the type of object, not the reference that defines which function gets binded in case you are overriding a method in superclass and calling that method.